# How do I generate TOC-only HTML from DocBook?

Tags: docbook

Given a Docbook-based XML file, how do I extract just the table of contents (TOC) into its own HTML file - preferably without resorting to writing my own XSLT template? I am using xsltproc.

I'm convinced that this must be obviously easy, but for some reason the solution escapes me - after having looked through the DocBook documentation.

As a bonus, I would like the generated *toc*.html file not to have any html/head/body...body/html wrappers in order to make it simple to embed it within a CMS-powered site.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. My DocBook-content is derived from AsciiDoc, though that should make no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the [SourceForge DocBook stylesheets](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/), you can use [chunking](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Chunking.html) with the [chunk.tocs.and.lots](http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/doc/html/chunk.tocs.and.lots.html) parameter. This generates a separate TOC file (and the other chunked HTML files as well).

Some options relevant to the bonus question are discussed in this thread:
http://www.mail-archive.com/docbook-apps@lists.oasis-open.org/msg09111.html

Comment: Thanks. Enabling chunk.tocs.and.lots parameter helped produce a ar01-toc.html file. Very close to what I wanted. Thanks again!